# What is this insect? Seems to be in Indonesia

Tags: species-identification, entomology

https://www.facebook.com/gadik63/videos/707361412787259/

This video has me completely baffled.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creatonotos_gangis

Creatonotos gangis is a species of arctiine moth found in South East Asia and Australia. It was described by Carl Linnaeus in his 1763 Centuria Insectorum.